# lubridate [R]: difference between a date and now() to be added to a date

Tags: r, intervals, lubridate

I am struggling a bit with lubridate

I have a date series in the past in df$mydate variable as POSIXct. I want to take `max(df$mydate)` subtract it from `now()`, then subtract 2 more days from that time interval - i.e. make the interval 2 days shorter than the difference between the latest date of the series and today. The obtained time interval then should be added to all dates in df$mydate so that the dates block is brought forward to end 2 days in the past from today.

How can I do this with lubridate?

when I try to convert `now() - max(df$mydate)` to interval I get an empty interval. So I do not even get to step 2 - shortening the interval by 2 days and to step 3 - trying to then add this time length to dates I have.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Idee with lubridate is to take care of all the transformation between intervals and dates for you so you don't need to think about it. This simple code does exactly that what you want.

```
library(lubridate)

my_date <-as.POSIXlt(paste0("2009-08-",1:10))
time_diff <- now() - max(my_date)
time_diff_short = time_diff - 2
my_date + time_diff_short
```

What I found was that you need my_date to be of the format `POSIXlt`

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well with my data being `Posixct`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `difftime` from *base* to get the time difference to *now* `Sys.time()` and subtract 2 days.

```
x <- x + (difftime(Sys.time(), max(x), units = "days") - 2)
x
#[1] "2020-09-11 10:32:20 CEST" "2020-09-12 10:32:20 CEST"
#[3] "2020-09-13 10:32:20 CEST" "2020-09-14 10:32:20 CEST"

Sys.time()
#[1] "2020-09-16 10:32:20 CEST"
```

Data:

```
(x <- seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 12:00:00"), length.out = 4, by = "days"))
#[1] "2000-01-01 12:00:00 CET" "2000-01-02 12:00:00 CET"
#[3] "2000-01-03 12:00:00 CET" "2000-01-04 12:00:00 CET"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works very well too. And does not need lubridate.